# hadoop cluster is not running mapreduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I set up a small Hadoop cluster following [these](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/spinning-up-a-free-hadoop-cluster-step-by-step-c406d56bae42) instructions but using Hadoop version 2.7.4. The cluster seems to work OK, but I cannot run mapreduce jobs. In particular, when trying the following

```
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.4.jar randomwriter outdenter code here
```

the job prints

```
17/11/27 16:35:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at 
ec2-yyy.eu-central-
1.compute.amazonaws.com/xxx:8032
Running 0 maps.

Job started: Mon Nov 27 16:35:22 UTC 2017

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at 
ec2-yyy.eu-central-
1.compute.amazonaws.com/xxx:8032


17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for 
job: job_1511799491035_0006

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application 
application_1511799491035_0006

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: 
http://ec2-yyy.eu-central-
1.compute.amazonaws.com:8088/proxy/application_1511799491035_0006/

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: 
job_1511799491035_0006
```

and never gets past this state.

My `yarn-site.xml` looks as follows

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property> 
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>ec2-yyy.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

My `mapred-site.xml` looks as follows

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>ec2-yyy.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:54311</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Do you have an idea how I could approach this issue?

Thanks
c14

Comment: If you're using Amazon, it'd be more useful to use EMR. Otherwise, it sounds like your jobs are too large... Go look at `The url to track the job` to inspect YARN resources

Comment: Hi, thanks. I went to the URL. Can you tell me a bit more precisely what to look for? Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's lots of things to look for, but for starters, is the job stare ACCEPTED, RUNNING, or FAILED?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. The state is "ACCEPTED"

Comment: Then if you enter that application attempt, does it say something  like "Waiting for resources"?

Comment: it says this: "ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM." Sorry, I should have found this myself and included in the OP

Comment: Right, so basically the application master (the process needed to start and monitor the job) cannot get enough resources from the cluster based on the input data you've specified, or default YARN memory container sizes. (I think these are 1 or 2G of RAM, and Amazon Micro instances do not have that)

Comment: OK. Thanks, but I am actually using m4.xlarge machines which should have enough memory.

Comment: Okay, then in the logs below, you put `max alloc vcore per queue for root is undefined`. You can find the documentation about the CapacityScheduler here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. Can you clarify what you mean by "in the logs below"? Thanks.

Comment: You commented on the answer below

Comment: So you think there is an issue with the capacityScheduler?

Comment: Just you've not configured it yet

Comment: I see. So I do a basic configuration of the capacityScheduler. do you know of a good basic configuration?

Comment: That's typically been done for me in the past. And I typically use Apache Ambari or Cloudera Manager to give a Hadoop Management UI, which recommends values for all those YARN settings based on the cluster size and hardware

Comment: OK, i might make a new question then. Thanks a lot.